# Declare integer or number value in json

Tags: javascript, json

now i am using json. The problem i am facing is i declared some values to pass to a chart. The values are read well but when passed to chart. It produces a runtime error showing its NaN(Not a Number). I include my Json file here

```
{
data: [
{
"value": 100
},
{
"value": 140
},
{
"value": 70
},
{
"value": 200
},
{
"value": 50
},
{
"value": 120
}]
}
```

Please figure out what the problem is or say how to include number data in json.

Comment: We need to see the code, the data is fine; Except that the key 'data' ought to be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid JSON. You need quotation marks around all identifiers:

```
{
"data": [
{
"value": 100
},
{
"value": 140
},
{
"value": 70
},
{
"value": 200
},
{
"value": 50
},
{
"value": 120
}]
}
```